# How to get all records from two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say we have two simple tables like:

```
**table1**                      **table2**
Nr   Color                      Id   Type
1    green                      43   metal
2    red                        52   glass
3    black                     
4    white
```

What I want to retrieve in my query is:

```
Nr   Color   Id   Type
1    green   43   metal
2    red     52   glass
3    black
4    white
```

Please help me.

Comment: What are the fields about link two tables?

Comment: There's no way to connect those tables, so there's no meaning in a result like that. Everything is possible in a DBMS, but why do you need this? You can do that in your client, too.

Comment: A relational database is about relations. Your tables are not related. There is no simple SQL query to solve this accordingly. If you want to show the data in this format, you should use SQL to select the data from one table first, then the other, and use your GUI client to care about the display.

Comment: Thanks, I  was not in the right way :) closing.

Comment: Technically you could join two unrelated tables by joining the row numbers... (though it would be a little tricky in MySQL)... but then again why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Its simply not possible, you need to do some trick here..

```
select Nr, Color, Id, Type
from (select @counter1 := @counter1+1 as counter, Nr, Color
      from table1, (select @counter1 := 0) init) t1
left join (select @counter2 := @counter2+1 as counter, Id, Type
           from table2, (select @counter2 := 0) init) t2
using (counter)
```

Produce result

```
Nr   Color   Id   Type
1    green   43   metal
2    red     52   glass
3    black
4    white
```

But as comment suggest best practice is define relation between tables.